# Error en ordenamiento por seleccion en java

Tags: java, algoritmos

estoy realizando un ejercicio con algoritmo de ordenamiento por seleccion de forma ascendente, sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto ordena solo el indice 0 del vector y me repite este mismo valor para el indice 1 del vector, y se pierde el otro valor, la verdad he mirado en varios sitios comparando mi codigo con otros y no veo error. aqui dejo el codigo para ver si uds pueden ver que error estoy cometiendo.

```
package VariablesyCondicionales;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;

public class OrdenamientoSeleccion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random r = new Random();
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);

        int ind_menor;

        int v1[] = {9,5};
        /*int v1[] = new int[2];

        v1[0]= r.nextInt(100);
        v1[1]= r.nextInt(100);*/


        p.println("Vector orignal\n");

        for(int i=0;i<v1.length;i++) {
            p.println("V"+i+"["+v1[i]+"]");
        }

        p.println("Vector organizado de manera ascendente con el metodo de Seleccion");

        for(int i=0;i<=v1.length-1;i++) {

            ind_menor=v1[i];
            for(int j=i+1;j<v1.length;j++) {
                if(v1[j]<ind_menor) {
                    ind_menor=v1[j];
                }               
            }
            if(v1[i] != ind_menor) {
                int aux = v1[i];
                v1[i] = ind_menor;
                ind_menor = aux ;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<v1.length;i++) {
            p.println("V"+i+"["+v1[i]+"]");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hiciste un debug? hay un error de logica, estas pasando a aux lo que contiene el v1[i], pero no estas intercambiando con el que estaba en aux (tal vez v1[j]?).. esta mal planteado el algoritmo..

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!, si aqui era aux toma lo que tiene la variable ind_menor, y anteriormente ind_menor =j

Answer (score 2):

En tu variable `ind_menor` debes guardar el índice del elemento, no el elemento como tal:

```
for(int i=0;i<=v1.length-1;i++) {

        p.println("iteracion: " + i);

        ind_menor=i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<v1.length;j++) {
            if(v1[j]<v1[ind_menor]) {
                ind_menor=j;
            }               
        }
        if(v1[i] != v1[ind_menor]) {
            int aux = v1[i];
            v1[i] = v1[ind_menor];
            v1[ind_menor] = aux ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias ! Funciono!! sin embargo puedes explicarme por que debo guardar el indice del elemento y no el elemento como tal, si ordeno es el valor que contiene no el indice, la verdad no entiendo. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Al guardar el índice del elemento en tu variable `ind_menor`, puedes acceder al valor pasándole el índice al arreglo. Es decir cuando llamas a `v1[ind_menor]` traes el valor guardado en el arreglo en la posición `ind_menor`.

Comment: @AndresG. puedes por favor aceptar la respuesta como correcta? Creo que ya solucioné tu pregunta

Answer (score -1):

Revisa que la selección debe ser sobre el indice y no sobre el valor del vector en el indice, o sea `ind_menor=i` en vez de `ind_menor=v1[i]`, siguiendo ésta regla tu código se vería así:

```
for(int i=0;i<=v1.length-1;i++) {    
    ind_menor=i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<v1.length;j++) {
        if(v1[j]<v1[ind_menor]) {
            ind_menor=i;
        }               
    }
    if(i != ind_menor) {
        int aux = v1[i];
        v1[i] = v1[ind_menor];
        v1[ind_menor] = aux ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es identica a la otra propuesta. Pero.. tiene un error, ind_menor=i; deberia ser ind_menor=j;

Comment: Cierto, pensé que buscaba un ordenamiento descendente...